# how to calculate average number of each person in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Hi i want to create a code that read a text file and print the average of each person in the file, i have this in the folder

```
boys.txt

ed lin,3,1,4,2
thomas block,6,3,3
```

```
Functions.py

def read_txt(file_txt):
    file = open(file_txt, "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    return lines
```

```
from Functions import read_txt

file_txt = input("input file: ")
read_txt(file_txt)

lines = (sum(lines)/len(lines))

print(lines)
```

so i want to print something like

```
ed lin: 2.5
thomas block: 4
```

but i dont know how to continue and with my code i get error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your other file to:

```
from Functions import read_txt

file_txt = input("input file: ")
lines read_txt(file_txt)

lines = '\n'.join(['%s: %s' % (line.split(',')[0], sum(list(map(int, line.strip().split(',')[1:]))) / len(line.strip().split(',')[1:])) for line in lines])

print(lines)
```

Output:

```
ed lin: 2.5
thomas block: 4
```

Comment: thank you, any way to do this in another way? i cant use string format like % or {, }, cant use for in, and cant use map() or filter(), the seminary wants me to learn how to do this without that

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are not allowed to use format, but without using it, it would be a little too tedious... In the meantime, here is another way you can do.

```
with open("boys.txt", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()

lines = contents.strip().split("\n")

for l in lines:
    boy = l.split(",")
    length = len(boy)
    score = 0
    for i in range(1, length):
         score += int(boy[i])
    average = score / (length-1)
    print("{}: {}".format(boy[0], average))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
from Functions import read_txt

file_txt = input("input file: ")
with open(file_txt, 'r') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  for line in lines:
    name = line[0: line.index(',')]
    data = [int(num) for num in (line[line.index(',')+1:].split(','))] 
    nums = len(data)
    data = sum(data)
    print(f"{name}: {data/nums}")
```